# Including my .jar files from lib folder to my main .jar file

Tags: build, jar

I have built a program in NetBeans, it creates myprogram.jar file but also creates folder named lib which includes JavaMail's mail.jar file. So I want to send that program to my friend without having to send him lib folder and telling him to put them together. So is there any way I can add all that in single .jar file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this kind of solution, which was wery easy to understand, doesn't include any other program than NetBeans and which worked excellent for me. Here is the link: http://javanepal.wordpress.com/2009/09/15/merging-jar-files-to-single-jar-via-ide-netbeans-6-7/

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken you cannot add jar files to jars.  What you can do is extract the contents of the jars you have (preserving the directory structure) and then jar the resulting directory hierarchy by follow the [instructions](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html) on how to create jar files

Of course once you figure out the exact commands involved, you could create a batch file to do the work for you again.

Comment: I don't think I can extract mail.jar because it is not made by me, it is JavaMail API's file. So what do I do when I want to distribute my program in single double clickable file?

Comment: You can extract _any_ jar files (they are essentially zip files): either rename it from .jar to .zip and extract it that way, or you can use the jar utility (specifically the [x option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html))

Comment: I extracted it and got like million class files and other stuff, what do I do with all that?

Comment: jar them up (along with your own classes) into one jar that you can give to your friend.  Actually, you will want to _not_ keep the mail.jar classes in the lib folder, but alongside your own classes

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: The jar utility will do that for you (see the link in my previous comments).  Look for the `c` option to create a jar